# Remove Masonry Loading Delay

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

For some reason Masonry is giving me a 2-3 second delay in "snapping" together after the window is loaded. Can anyone figure out why?

http://ten-thousand-10000.tumblr.com/

Comment: Your masonry initialisation code is inside: `$(window).load()`. This means the window has to be *fully* loaded, before masonry even starts building, which explains the delay. Ref: http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Comment: Thanks! Part of the delay was also caused by long image load times and unreasonable amounts of assets being pulled from tumblr. This was a big help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117195/masonry-style-layout-only-with-css