# How to make the down divs go up along side others div

Tags: css, css-float

I want to make all divs side by side.

I mean remove the space form top of the `#div3` and `#div4`.

I tried `float` and `display:inline-block`

my code :

```
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">The first</div>
    <div id="div2">next to each other.</div>
    <div id="div3">The two divs are</div>
    <div id="div4">The two divs are</div>
</div>
#div1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:220px;
    height:120px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#div2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:260px;
    height:260px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#div3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:160px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#div4 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:160px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u5y6tuwm/

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [**flex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) in the parent container:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  /*set display to flex*/
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#wrapper > div {
  margin-right: 10px;
  /*add some margin to the right to direct children div*/
}
#div1 {
  width: 220px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#div2 {
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#div3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#div4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="div1">The first</div>
  <div id="div2">next to each other.</div>
  <div id="div3">The two divs are</div>
  <div id="div4">The two divs are</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to each div1, 2, 3 and 4

you can add this to affect all divs on the page

```
div {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

or this for all divs within #wrapper div

```
#wrapper div {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

or this to target each div you want ( 1-4 )

```
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

or to each one individually, or inline style and so on.

Comment: Hmm, I think maybe you mean a masonry style layout, for if div 3 and 4 are below div 1 and 2? If so, the responses to the following question will help you learn about it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117195/masonry-style-layout-only-with-css > or here < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196082/bootstrap-how-to-stack-divs-of-different-heights?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add

```
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {
    float:left;
}
```

This will work perfectly. Also do not forget to clear the float after