# Fullscreen bootstrap grid with different sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, masonry

I'm trying to create a fullscreen bootstrap grid with different heights (33.33%, 66.66% or 100%) and different widths (20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100%).

The problem is that because of the height difference gaps occur.

http://www.bootply.com/BXENv65tq8#

[image]

I found a couple of solutions already but none of them are realy working like they should: wrong margins, cannot get it fullscreen,...

[Masonry-style Layout ONLY with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117195/masonry-style-layout-only-with-css)

My result (from highest rated anwer):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the way you're using the  you can not get the result shown in the first box. to achieve this need to organize your div for columns and not by rows.

Here's an [example](http://www.bootply.com/N4L2wcJlsV) that perhaps you can help