# Is there a way to sort children into columns depending on the class of the children?

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

Let's say that I have the following HTML code.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div style='width: 50px; height: random' class='col1'>1</div>
    <div style='width: 50px; height: random' class='col3'>2</div>
    <div style='width: 50px; height: random' class='col2'>3</div>
    <div style='width: 50px; height: random' class='col3'>4</div>
    <div style='width: 50px; height: random' class='col1'>5</div>
    <div style='width: 50px; height: random' class='col2'>6</div>
    <div style='width: 50px; height: random' class='col1'>7</div>
    <div style='width: 50px; height: random' class='col3'>8</div>
    <div style='width: 50px; height: random' class='col2'>9</div>
</div>

<!-

|1| |3| |2| // height of 2 is greater
|5| |6| | | // height of 5 is greater
| | |9| |4| // height of 9 is greater
|7| | | |8|

->
```

I want `container` to have 3 columns. I also want each child to be sorted into one of those columns based on its class. Obviously, it would be easy to do this with JavaScript but I'm wondering if it's possible to do it with CSS.

```css
.grid {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 15px;
  column-fill: auto;
}
.block {
  background-color: #ee01ca;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
}

.one {
  height: 100px;
}

.two {
  height: 200px;
}

.three {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="block one">ervewrv</div>
  <div class="block two">afrvewrwerb</div>
  <div class="block three">dfvdsf</div>
  <div class="block one">vdfvdf</div>
  <div class="block two">dfw45g4</div>
  <div class="block one">ervewrv</div>
  <div class="block two">afrvewrwerb</div>
  <div class="block three">dfvdsf</div>
  <div class="block one">vdfvdf</div>
  <div class="block two">dfw45g4</div>
  <div class="block three">4rv4r</div>
  <div class="block one">4rv454</div>
  <div class="block three">4rv4r</div>
  <div class="block one">4rv454</div>
  <div class="block one">ervewrv</div>
  <div class="block one">ervewrv</div>
  <div class="block two">afrvewrwerb</div>
  <div class="block three">dfvdsf</div>
  <div class="block one">vdfvdf</div>
  <div class="block two">dfw45g4</div>
  <div class="block three">4rv4r</div>
  <div class="block one">4rv454</div>
  <div class="block one">ervewrv</div>
  <div class="block two">afrvewrwerb</div>
  <div class="block three">dfvdsf</div>
  <div class="block one">vdfvdf</div>
  <div class="block two">dfw45g4</div>
  <div class="block three">4rv4r</div>
  <div class="block one">4rv454</div>
  <div class="block two">afrvewrwerb</div>
  <div class="block three">dfvdsf</div>
  <div class="block one">vdfvdf</div>
  <div class="block two">dfw45g4</div>
  <div class="block one">ervewrv</div>
  <div class="block two">afrvewrwerb</div>
  <div class="block three">dfvdsf</div>
  <div class="block one">vdfvdf</div>
  <div class="block two">dfw45g4</div>
  <div class="block three">4rv4r</div>
  <div class="block one">4rv454</div>
  <div class="block three">4rv4r</div>
  <div class="block one">4rv454</div>
</div>
```

This is similar to the effect I'm after except I need the sorting to be done left to right. So in the example, `ervewrv` should be left of `afrvewrwerb`.

Comment: everything is random ? number of element, height, ?

Comment: The number of children is dynamic along with the height of each child. There is a maximum value for the height but I don't think that changes anything.

Comment: no sure if you can find a solution with pure CSS .. but you can check flex and the order property ... at least you can re-roder your element then you have to find how to setup the column

Comment: Yeah, I was looking into that earlier and couldn't find the solution there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS grid may work for your layout.

Use `grid-column` value to order your content.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.container >div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
}

.col1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.col2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.col3 {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='col1' style="height: 80px;">1</div>
  <div class='col3'>2</div>
  <div class='col2'>3</div>
  <div class='col3' style="height: 100px;">4</div>
  <div class='col1'>5</div>
  <div class='col2'>6</div>
  <div class='col1'>7</div>
  <div class='col3'>8</div>
  <div class='col2'>9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's essentially what I'm looking for. Is there a way to get the grid items height to be dynamic? In other words, can each grid items height be independent of the row it's in? **EDIT: In your example, the second column would be the shortest column.**

Comment: I don't think so. You're describing a masonry layout. This question might be of some use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917346/masonry-layout-with-css-grid

Comment: @JohnCullen nope, the closest you can get is to have variable row spans on the elements, but not dynamic heights. CSS Grid will always behave... as a grid.